# Are PHP script read from Top to bottom?

Tags: php

Are PHP scripts reads from top to bottom? like HTML? because in this code

```
<?php require_once("./includes/connection.php")?>
<?php require_once("./includes/functions.inc.php"); ?>
<?php 

    if(isset($_GET['subj']))
    {
        $sel_subj = get_subject_by_id($_GET['subj']);
        $sel_page = NULL;

    }else if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $sel_subj = NULL;
        $sel_page = get_page_by_id($_GET['page']);
    }else
    {
        $sel_subj = NULL;
        $sel_page = NULL;
    }


?>
<?php include("includes/header.inc.php"); ?>
<table id="structure">
    <tr>
        <td id="navigation">
            <ul class = "subjects">
                <?php

                    $subject_set = get_all_subjects();

                    while($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set))
                    {
                        echo "<li";
                        if($subject['id'] == $sel_subj['id']) {echo " class =\"selected\"";}
                        echo "><a href=\"content.php?subj=" . urlencode($subject["id"]) . 
                        "\">{$subject["menu_name"]}</a></li>";

                        echo "<ul class = 'pages'>";

                        $page_set = get_pages_for_subject($subject['id']);

                        while($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set))
                        {
                            echo "<li"; 
                            if($page['id'] == $sel_page['id']){echo " class = \"selected\"";}
                            echo"><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($page["id"]) .
                            "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
                        }
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                ?>
                </ul>
        </td>
        <td id="page">
                <?php if(isset($sel_subj)){?>
                    <h2><?php echo "{$sel_subj['menu_name']}";?></h2>
                <?php } ?>  
                <?php if(isset($sel_page)){?>
                    <h2><?php echo "{$sel_page['menu_name']}"?> </h2>
                <?php }?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php require("includes/footer.inc.php"); ?>
```

specifically this part

```
if(isset($_GET['subj']))
        {
            $sel_subj = get_subject_by_id($_GET['subj']);
            $sel_page = NULL;

        }else if(isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $sel_subj = NULL;
            $sel_page = get_page_by_id($_GET['page']);
        }else
        {
            $sel_subj = NULL;
            $sel_page = NULL;
        }
```

How is this if-else block being called if it's on top of the page?

Comment: Yes they are. Are you seeing something else happen?

Comment: Do you understand that the PHP is reprocessed "top-to-bottom" every time a new page is loaded? That is, on each page hit, exactly one of those three `if` conditions will be met depending on what is on the URL.

Comment: I was just wondering how did $_GET  variable gets its value even though the page doesn't contain any "subj" in its url. subj will be given value if the user clicks any of the menu.

Comment: It gets it from the previous iteration of the page.

Comment: @Matthew oh I see. so PHP is reprocessed from top to bottom on each page hit. That answer or should I say comment answered my query. I was going to select you as best answer but apparently  I can't since you commented.

Comment: @user962206, I just added an answer that explains it in a bit more depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is run top-to-bottom one time *per page view*. On the initial view, assuming the URL has no parameters, then neither `$_GET['subj']` or `$_GET['page']` will be set.

If the link pointing back to the same page is clicked, then the entire PHP file will be reprocessed. If that link contained `subj` or `page` in the URL as a query variable, then the corresponding `if` block will be executed and the page will be altered accordingly.

Think of the PHP server as dynamically creating some HTML file that is sent to the web browser. Once it is sent, the server is done, and the PHP code is "gone." The only way to run more PHP code is to request a new page, where the process starts over.

(Even AJAX follows the same principles, although generally then you are dealing with partial data requests as opposed to full page views.)

Comment: I can view a page a hundred times, even offline, so PHP is not exectued. There is no 1:1 relation between the view of some programs output and the run of the program itself. Technically wrong, because it's common to cache program output.

Comment: True. I should have also mentioned that if somebody is watching the screen over your shoulder, then the PHP code is *not* executed twice. Similarly, if the monitor is off and nobody views the HTML when the request is made, the PHP code still will run.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, scripts are run from top to bottom.  I don't understand why you think that if-else block is any different?  Those if clauses are run to set the `$sel_subj` and `$sel_page` variables before the rest of the page is executed and output.

Comment: How does  $_GET  gets its value? because $_GET['subj'] supposed to be null? there is no value of "subj" in the url when the page runs. unless I click any of the menus.

Comment: Right, $_GET['subj'] has no value.  That's why they're using `if(isset($_GET['subj']))` to see if it does or it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

PHP scripts are executed from top-to-bottom. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Short answers like this are probably best as comments, to which a (more substantial) answer can be given in response.